# Type guard indexed property access - Typescript

Tags: typescript

This is failing with the message left/right hand side of an arithmatic operation should be of type 'number', 'bigint' etc ....

```
  sort({ key, direction }: SortOptions<Listing>) {
    this.dataSet.sort((a, b) => { // <--- dataSet: Listing[]
      let returnVal;
      if (typeof a[key] === 'number' && typeof b[key] === 'number')
        returnVal = a[key] - b[key]; // <-- error here
      ...
      return direction === 'asc' ? returnVal : -returnVal;
      });
  }
```

key is already type checked to be a `keyof T` where a and b are of type T.

```
interface SortOptions<T> {
  key: keyof T;
  direction: 'asc' | 'desc';
}

export interface Listing {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  condition: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  stock: number;
  sold: boolean;
  display: boolean;
}
```

If I remove type checking on key, i.e. `SortOptions<Listing>` the error is not shown. But this is because then there is no type safety as `key` is `any` and `a[key]` is also `any`

I know that there are simple javascript ways like `+a[key]` to make this work. But I'm trying to get the type checking right.

Comment: Probably because typeof NaN is also a 'number' :).

Comment: You can extract `a[key]` and `b[key]` to variables, then typeguard will work

Comment: @AlekseyL. i had a feeling this might be a compiler limitation. Do you know why though? Also, thanks, feel free to leave an answer, i'll vote for it.

Comment: @hazardous nope, look at this. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: I can't find any documentation or issue on this topic, so I don't know if this "by design" or bug..

Comment: @AlekseyL. just a wild guess: getters in JS can mutate values, so after running `typeof a[key] === 'number'` there is no guarantee `a[key]` would return the same value in the next statement.

Comment: @zerkms but `if (typeof foo.bar === 'number') foo.bar - 1;` works for some reason. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%20bar%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20foo%3A%20Foo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(typeof%20foo%5B'bar'%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20foo%5B'bar'%5D%20-%201%3B)

Comment: @AlekseyL. indeed it does, while it's possible to trick it tinyurl.com/y2nvhyrc

Comment: @zerkms sure, I understand what you're saying. I'm just thinking that this is not related to why `a[key] === 'number'` doesn't work. If it was - my example also shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue that TypeScript doesn't do control-flow analysis narrowing on object property checks in all cases. Some currently missing use cases: [property checks on index signatures with square brackets](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28081); [property checks on values of generic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4742).  Some such cases were recently addressed, but there still seems to be a hole if you use indexed access on a non-literal key.  (Not sure which existing issue, if any, this falls under).  I'm not sure if this particular use case will ever get resolved, since prior fixes have had performance penalties.

In any case, such type guard narrowing works better on variables than it does on expressions of variables (like property accesses), so when in doubt, a reasonable workaround is to assign the expression you care about to its own variable:

```
sort({ key, direction }: SortOptions<Listing>) {
    this.dataSet.sort((a, b) => { // <--- dataSet: Listing[]
        let returnVal;
        const aKey = a[key]; // assign to new variable
        const bKey = b[key]; // assign to new variable
        if (typeof aKey === 'number' && typeof bKey === 'number') // check variables
            returnVal = aKey - bKey; // no error now
        ...    
        return direction === 'asc' ? returnVal : -returnVal;
    });
}
```

This should work as you expect.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Actually it [does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%20bar%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20foo%3A%20Foo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(typeof%20foo%5B'bar'%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20foo%5B'bar'%5D%20-%201%3B), but not in this specific case

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  Literal keys are checked even via bracket access; I’ve edited my answer to specify property access of a non-literal index.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But now linked issue seems to be not related (and fixed)

Comment: Hmm, I think the linked issue was related but they only fixed part of it (or at least there are related issues closed as duplicates).  I will ask if [Microsoft/TypeScript#28081](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28081) or [Microsoft/TypeScript#4742](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4742) are sufficiently close or if this is a separate issue.

Comment: It might also be [Microsoft/TypeScript#22214](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22214)